# Why do many Win32 Strucs contain their size as a member

Tags: c, windows, winapi, design-patterns

This is not strictly a programming question but more of a design question.

Working with some strucs from the WinAPI I noticed that many of them contain a field called `dwSize` that simpally stores their size e.g [THREADENTRY32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-threadentry32) or [BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/ns-bluetoothapis-bluetooth_device_search_params)

```
typedef struct tagTHREADENTRY32 {
DWORD dwSize;
DWORD cntUsage;
DWORD th32ThreadID;
DWORD th32OwnerProcessID;
LONG  tpBasePri;
LONG  tpDeltaPri;
DWORD dwFlags;
} THREADENTRY32;
```

Thinking about this design i find it intriguing why can't the code that using those structures use  `sizeof`?

What is the actual thinking behind this?

Comment: One possibility is that there are different versions of the structure. Newer code may have more fields in the structure. By having the size in there it allows old client code to call updated implementations of some APIs and vice versa. In this case for example, a pointer to the struct is passed to the `Thread32First` function. That function may have a different definition of the struct. Having the size there tells the function how many bytes of the struct it can write to and the function can fill in the size to tell the calling code how many bytes were written.

Comment: Iow, Its a really crappy way of "versioning" struct layout to future-proof functional expansion of the apis that use them.

Comment: @who What would a less crappy versioning scheme look like, in your opinion?

Comment: @IInspectable An actual API version number provided by macro. That way MS wouldn't necessarily have to change the size of the struct artificially in the circumstance where the size wouldn't normally change but the layout would.

Comment: Back in the day, that was considered the best way to keep your options open for future versions of Windows instead of creating new structs every time a Windows version came along. Windows has been around many many years and those structures have evolved a lot. Whether it was a good decision or not, well I dunno.

Comment: Related: [Why are structure sizes checked strictly?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031212-00/?p=41523)

Comment: @who How is this less crappy? Now you're forcing clients to supply extrinsic data they have to look up rather than use an intrinsic property of the structure.

Comment: @IInspectable the downside of `sizeof(STRUCTNAME)` is that it can break on older Windows versions just by updating your compiler/SDK. Setting `foo.v = FOO_V1` will never break ABI.

Comment: @anders Is there any precedent where a size-versioned symbol in the Windows SDK was renamed, breaking the ABI? Obviously maintaining ABI stability isn't something that comes for free. I don't see how using a structure's size is any more at risk of introducing an ABI break than an explicit named version constant. Now if updating your compiler breaks your ABI then clearly you should be filing a bug with your compiler vendor.

Comment: @IIns There are many examples of the size changing, OPENFILENAME changing in 2000 being one. I never said one was renamed although in DirectInput structs were actually renamed and larger ones taking their old name.

Comment: @anders I was specifically asking for a precedent where a structure that uses the structure size as a version indicator broke code just because clients compiled against a different SDK. I'm not aware of any such, which is not to say that this never happened. But if you're making a call that using the structure size as a version indicator were somehow problematic, you're going to have to provide a bit more evidence than an opinion, that a name version constant were more robust.

Comment: @IIns Win95: sizeof(OPENFILENAME). Windows 2000, oops, we had to add the OPENFILENAME_SIZE_VERSION_400 define and all apps have to switch to that if they want to work on 95/98/nt4 when using new SDK.

Comment: @anders Dude... I'm not asking about issues when targeting **completely different operating systems**. But I see you're much more interested in being right rather than providing evidence for an opinion (that - to be perfectly honest - is absolutely unfounded). Now worries, the age-old *"Micro$oft sucks"* flies, even around here. No evidence required to earn some giggles.

Comment: How much evidence do you need? Given app X that runs on 95/98. Upgrade Visual Studio 6 to 2003. Open dialog no longer works on 95/98 just because you changed your tool chain.

Comment: @anders Evidence that the procedure to version structures by size were unsound. Not just some random anecdotal evidence that *someone* succeeded to fumble it.

Comment: @IIns "If you take the Windows 2000 version of this structure and pass it to Windows NT 4, the call will fail since the sizes don’t match." https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031212-00/?p=41523

Comment: @anders You only get the Windows 2000 structure size if you **explicitly** ask for it, i.e. if you set your minimum supported target to Windows 2000. If your minimum supported target is Windows 2000, then clearly you aren't planning to support Windows NT 4.0. The fact that the code will fail to execute on a version of Windows earlier than your minimum supported target is to be expected. What's the precise point you were trying to make?

Comment: @IIns Actually, you will get the larger size unless you explicitly ask for the old version because WINVER gets set for you. WINVER is broken by design in the real world because apps often want the option of using new APIs when available without having to duplicate all required defines and structs. If Windows had done a >= check on the size there would be no issue but alas it does == in places.

Comment: @anders `WINVER` gets set for you **only if you don't care**, i.e. if you don't set it. If you do care about your minimum supported target then things don't change from underneath you. There's not a single place in all of the Windows SDK where a `#define WINVER` doesn't have an `#ifndef WINVER` right before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to support future versions of that structure that might have new fields added to it.

Comment: See [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)'s `lpStartupInfo` argument for an example.

Comment: The size prefix is brilliant.  In addition to telling the receiver what version of the struct you're using, it attests that you've got your compiler's member alignment options set correctly, in such a way that buffer overruns are prevented even if you don't.

Comment: Also, it allows the code inside the method to know which fields it can write to without a this-field-was-introduced-in-this-version map, by checking the field offset against the size.